# Translating touch events from Javascript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, iphone, mobile

I am using

```
window.addEventListener("touchstart", function(ev){
    console.log(ev.touches); // good
});
```

How can I translate this to jQuery?  I've tried:

```
$(window).bind("touchstart",function(ev){
    console.log(ev.touches); // says ev.touches is undefined
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: thanks, relatively new to the site. just went back and approved answers that were good.

Comment: No worries. Glad you figured things out :)

Comment: A simple jQuery library: https://github.com/Tundra-Interactive/swipe.jquery.js

Comment: I'm confused, does this only work with browsers that recognize touch? If you simply wanted know when an element is touched (in a browser that recognizes touch events), would this suffice? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

jQuery 'fixes up' events to account for browser differences.  When it does so, you can always access the 'native' event with `event.originalEvent` (see the Special Properties subheading on [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)).

Answer (score 45):

```
$(window).on("touchstart", function(ev) {
    var e = ev.originalEvent;
    console.log(e.touches);
});
```

I know it been asked a long time ago, but I thought a concrete example might help.

Comment: Thanks for taking the notion of a "concrete example" being beneficial seriously.